# Importing files modulenotfounderror

Tags: python, django

I have looked on multiple stackoverflow post but cannot find the answer.
I have the following file structure i am also doing this in a django project

```
crypto_api_site
    bitvavo_api
        bitvavowallet.py
        data.py
    main
        views.py
```

Where data.py imports bitvavowallet.py and views.py imports data.py .
But when executing `python manage.py runserver`
I keep getting the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitvavowallet'`

my import in views.py looks like this
`sys.path.append('crypto_api_site/bitvavo_api/')`

`from bitvavo_api import data`

and my import in data.py looks like this

`import bitvavowallet`

I also added `__init__.py` in the directories
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can try to add `__init__.py` in the directories.

Comment: import bitvavowallet.py => import bitvavowallet